# Can't install grub if mbr contains iso9660

Tags: grub2

I installed Debian/Gnu-Linux on a disk which previously contained an ISO9660 filesystem, and grub can't be installed :

```
root@debian:~# grub-install /dev/sdb
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: hd1 appears to contain a iso9660 filesystem which isn't known to reserve space for DOS-style boot.  Installing GRUB there could result in FILESYSTEM DESTRUCTION if valuable data is overwritten by grub-setup (--skip-fs-probe disables this check, use at your own risk).
```

I was able to install it on an other disk currently plugged on the machine (/dev/sda), but I'd like to get rid of it.

I tried `install-mbr /dev/sdb`, hoping it would erase the ISO9660 blocks, but I still get the error with grub-install.

I could probably copy some blocks of /dev/sda to /dev/sdb, but how many of them ?

Comment: I finally managed to get it working by invoking grub-setup directly : `grub-setup --force --skip-fs-probe /deb/sdb`.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the mbr (master boot recored) using the dd command. A master boot record (MBR) is the 512-byte boot sector that is the first sector of a partitioned data storage device of a hard disk.

#### Understanding MBR size

The mbr size is as follows in bytes:

```
446 bytes - Bootstrap.
64 bytes - Partition table.
2 bytes - Signature.
= 512 bytes
```

***WARNING!*** These examples may crash your computer if executed. The following command will completely delete your MBR including all your partition information. So make sure you use the correct device name and block size in bytes.

#### Delete mbr including all partitions

Open a terminal and type the following command command to delete everything:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1
```

Sample output:

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.00308483 s, 166 kB/s
```

Where,

```
if=/dev/zero - Read data from /dev/zero and write it to /dev/sdc.
of=/dev/sdc - /dev/sdc is the USB drive to remove the MBR including all partitions.
bs=512 - Read from /dev/zero and write to /dev/sdc up to 512 BYTES bytes at a time.
count=1 - Copy only 1 BLOCK input blocks.
```

#### Command to delete mbr only

The following command will erase mbr, but not your partitions:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=446 count=1
```

Where,

```
bs=446 - Read from /dev/zero and write to /dev/sdc up to 446 BYTES bytes at a time.
```

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-clearing-out-master-boot-record-dd-command/)

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get it working by invoking grub-setup directly :

```
grub-setup --force --skip-fs-probe /dev/sdX
```

Grub-setup spit a few warnings but I was able to boot an the disk again.